# How to Update in the GridView if the headers are not databound

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]
I have a `GridView`, and the header field of the `GridView` are the items from a `ListBox` in my program. Therefore the number of columns generated is dynamic every time I run. So when I click on **Update** in the `Gridview`, the data entered in `TextBox` of that row has to be updated irrespective of the header field. Also the `TextBox` should be validated to accept only integer.

The .cs code for `GridView` display is:

```
protected void DONE4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow rw = default(DataRow);
        for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(ListBox1.Items[i].ToString(),System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            rw = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                rw[ListBox1.Items[i].ToString()] = " ";
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(rw);
        }
        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me on this issue with a code for Updating? Thank you..
Hope the question is clear.

Comment: My `GridView` is not bound to any datasource, so how to update the rows w.r.t headers that are unknown.

Comment: You have to state your code for data-binding to make the question clear for all

Comment: dst.Tables[0].Columns["Profile_Instance"].ColumnName == "Profile_Instance" right ? :)

Comment: please elaborate on "header field of the GridView are the items from a ListBox in my program" show us the gridview markup code too

Comment: You have not databound gridview. I think You simply want to ask, How to do update in unbound gridview. Am I right? If this is the case, I can post the answer. If not, then correct me, still there will be answer.

Comment: You are getting only one field in gridview? You should get two. Id or Primary key and Profile_Instance. Even if you do not want to show, hide the primary key field, but it will help you easily and accurately update. I have code for you. You can try that.

Comment: @SamiAkram Yes I want an update for unbound `GridView`. FYI : I have a  `ListBox1` whose items are the headers of the `GridView`. The code that I have put in my question shows how I have used ListBox1 has headers of `GridView`

Comment: Header do not matter. Right Now I am here. Waiting for your response. Can you do something To Add a primary key field to your query? The query which fills your datatable and then GridView

Comment: Lately I have attached my screenshots. Hope that explains everything.

Comment: Can I know to which query am I suppose to add a primary key? Because I my database is not design with any primary key.

Comment: Ok I will do that. So I hope you know what I am trying to do here. Thank you. I will wait for your answer.

Comment: Where you want to store updated value in database or listbox?

Comment: If in database then why you are using distinct. In fact you should tell what you want to achieve

Comment: Just write few values for profile_instance and of primary key column from database in question